# NameError: name 'Pt1' is not defined

Tags: python

En mi primer programa en Python me sale el siguiente error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Pt1.py", line 5,
> in 
> class Pt1:   File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Pt1.py", line 44,
> in Pt1
> menuOpciones()   File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\venv\Pt1.py", line 13,
> in menuOpciones
> Pt1.exercici1_1() NameError: name 'Pt1' is not defined

Este es el codigo:

```
import os
import sys

class Pt1:

    def exercici1_1 ():
        with open ("workData.txt", "w") as work_data:
            print("Escribe lo que quieras")
            work_data.write(input() + '\n')

    def menuOpciones ():
        Pt1.exercici1_1()

        salir = False

        while not salir:

            print("1. Opcion 1")
            print("2. Opcion 2")
            print("3. Opcion 3")
            print("4. Salir\n")

            opcion = int (input("Introduce una opcion: "))

            if opcion == 1:
                exercici1_1()
            elif opcion == 2:
                print("Opcion 2")
            elif opcion == 3:
                print("Opcion 3")
            elif opcion == 4:
                salir = True
                break
            else:
                print("Introduce un numero entre 1 y 3")

        print("Fin")


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        menuOpciones()
```

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta corta: Elimina la línea `class Pt1` y toda referencia a Pt1.

En este problema no necesitas una clase y estás ocupando la sintaxis y semántica equivocada para crear una.

Una clase comienza así:

```
class Pt1:
    def __init__(self, par1, par2, ...):
        self.par1 = par1
        self.par2 = par2
         ...
```

Una clase es un modelo para crear objetos. Una clase tiene que tener un método `__init__` para iniciarlos los objetos que construye. Este método puede tener un número variable de parámetros.

Otra característica de una clase es que todos sus métodos (funciones) reciben siempre como primer parámetro el objeto (de la clase) sobre el cual hay que trabajar. Por ejemplo:

```
class Pt1:
    ...
    def recuperar(self, llave):
         ...
```

Ojo, que no necesitas poner el parámetro `self` al invocar el método; Python se encarga de eso:

```
dato = cliente.recuperar("K001")
```

donde `cliente` es un objeto de la clase Pt1.

Cada objeto de la clase contiene su propia copia de los atributos de la clase, los que persisten durante la vida del objeto. Para referirse a ellos dentro de un método, usas la forma `self.nombre`, como ya se ha mostrado.